# ¿Cómo imprimir las frecuencias de cada numero?

Tags: array, c, frecuencia

Ya pude crear el codigo en donde se imprime la frecuencia del numero que más se repitió, pero necesito la frecuencia de cada número, sin embargo no logro hacerlo. Alguien que tenga idea de como hacerlo?

Realiza un programa que genere de manera aleatoria 100 números en el intervalo del
conjunto del 1 al 20, y después
genera una lista con la frecuencia de cada número.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


int main() 
{
srand(time(0));
int arreglo[100];
int i,j, c,c1, frecuencia;

for(i=0;i<=99;i++) {
arreglo[i] =rand()% 20+1 ;
printf("\n %i ", arreglo[i]);
}

c1=-1;
for(i=0; i<=100; i++)
{
  c=0;
  for(j=0; j<=99; j++)
  {
      if(arreglo[i]==arreglo[j])
      {
          c=c+1;
      }
  }
  if(c>c1)
  {
      frecuencia=arreglo[i];
      c1=c;
  }
}

 printf("\n La frecuencia es de:%i", frecuencia);


 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    int NUMERO_MAS_ALTO = 20;       // Este numero es limite superir del intervalo de numeros

    srand(time(0));
    int arreglo[100];
    int i,j, c,c1, frecuencia;

    int frecuencias[NUMERO_MAS_ALTO + 1];   // En el array se almacenan las frecuancias por su indice
    int numero_aleatorio;

    // Inicializamos el array de conteo de frecuencias en 0
    for(int i=0; i<NUMERO_MAS_ALTO; i++)
    {
        frecuencias[i] = 0;
    }

    // Asignacion de numeros aleatorios en el array
    for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
    {
        numero_aleatorio = rand() % 20+1;
        arreglo[i] = numero_aleatorio;
        frecuencias[numero_aleatorio] += 1; // Contamos el numero que salio
        printf("\n %i ", arreglo[i]);
    }

    c1 = -1;
    for(i=0; i<=100; i++)
    {
        c=0;
        for(j=0; j<=99; j++)
        {
            if(arreglo[i]==arreglo[j])
            {
                c=c+1;
            }
        }
        if(c>c1)
        {
            frecuencia=arreglo[i];
            c1=c;
        }
    }

    // imprimimos las frecuencias de cada numero
    for(int i=0; i<NUMERO_MAS_ALTO; i++)
    {
        printf("NUmero %i se repite %i\n",i, frecuencias[i]);
    }
    printf("\n La frecuencia es de:%i", frecuencia);
    return 0;
}
```